# JQuery function in repeater only works once

Tags: jquery, html, jquery.repeater

I'm using jquery-repeater library to create dynamic input in table. Each row will calculate the average value based on keyup event :

```
=============================
Col A | Col B | Col C | AVG |
=============================
1     | 2     | 3     | 2   |
2     | 3     | 4     | 3   |
...
```

Col A, B, C are input field. Users can add several rows as needed, and each row will show the average in last column (AVG).

This is my code (View using JQuery-repeater) :

```js
$("input[type=number]", "#table").keyup(function() {
  var $parent = $(this).parents('tr');
  var allInputs = $("input[type=number]", $parent);
  var total = 0;
  $.each(allInputs, function() {
    total += $(this).val() === '' ? +0 : +$(this).val();
  });

  $(".avg", $parent).val(total / 3);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" class="table repeater" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <center>A - B</center>
      </th>
      <th>
        <center>A - C</center>
      </th>
      <th>
        <center>B - C</center>
      </th>
      <th>
        <center>AVG</center>
      </th>
      <th>
        <center>
          <button data-repeater-create id="add_data">
            Add Data
          </button>
        </center>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-repeater-list="data">
    <tr data-repeater-item>
      <td><input type="number" name="val1"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="val2"></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="val3"></td>
      <td><input name="avg" class="avg" readonly></td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <button data-repeater-delete>Delete</button>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I expect the function could work in each row, but the actual is the function only works once.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6u0b3ozr/)

Comment: btw, don't use `center` this is deprecated. use CSS instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your rows is dynamically created so you need to add event to it in this way:

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#table input[type=number]", function(){})
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ek798bvn/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to attach listeners for the newly added row. [Modified Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nidhingeorgejoseph/Lyb8n9hc/4/)

Each time we add listener to the last row added using `$("input[type=number]", "#table tr:last-child")`.

```
$('.repeater').repeater({
  show: function() {
    $(this).slideDown();
    attachListeners();
  }
});

function attachListeners() {
  $("input[type=number]", "#table tr:last-child").keyup(function() {
    var $parent = $(this).parents('tr');
    var allInputs = $("input[type=number]", $parent);
    var total = 0;
    $.each(allInputs, function() {
      total += $(this).val() === '' ? +0 : +$(this).val();
    });

    $(".avg", $parent).val(total / 3);
  });
}

attachListeners();
```